# Writing data to a csv file line by line in python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I would like to extract data with cur.fetchmany(size) to write it into a csv file and finally using cur.copy_from() to copy that data to another table. I am aware that there are other solutions but my way has to be like data-csv-table. I have more than 100k rows and am trying to iterate cur.fetchmany() method to do it part by part. In my code youc an see I defined a function to write csv and iterate data. I added the error. I looked for the errpr but couldn't find solution which suits my question. My question is: Why do I get that error and what should I do to fix it as I mentioned below?

```py
import psycopg2
import csv

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = 'user', password = 'password',host='192.850.1.45', database = 'test', port = 5432)

cur = connection.cursor()
print('Database connected successfully')
cur.execute('Select cust_ord_id::bigint, cust_ord_item_id::bigint from dwf_sales limit 10000')

def csvyaz(num):
    with open('C:/Users/oguz.catal/Desktop/newfile.csv', 'wb', ) as filecsv:
        writer = csv.writer(filecsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        writer.writerow(num)
    return 'C:/Users/oguz.catal/Desktop/newfile.csv'

def iter_row(cursor, size=1000):
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(size)
        num = list(sum(rows, ()))
        if rows is None:
            break
        for row in rows:
            yield row
        print(num)
        csvyaz(num)
        t = open('C:/Users/oguz.catal/Desktop/newfile.csv', 'r+')
        cur.copy_from(t,'oguz_deneme',sep=',', null='null', columns=('cust_ord_id', 'cust_ord_item_id'))

for row in iter_row(cur, 1000):
    print(row)
```

I get this error:

> 'Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "C:/Users/oguz.catal/PycharmProjects/untitled/fetchmannny.py", line
>   34, in   for row in iter_row(cur, 1000):  File
>   "C:/Users/oguz.catal/PycharmProjects/untitled/fetchmannny.py", line
>   31, in iter_row  cur.copy_from(t,'oguz_deneme',sep=',', null='null',
>   columns=('cust_ord_id', 'cust_ord_item_id')) 
>   psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: extra data after last expected
>   column  CONTEXT:  COPY oguz_deneme, line 1:
>   "6800008477,4400033838,6800008477,4400033834,6800008477,4400033832,6800008477,4400033827,6800008732,4..."'

My csv is like this:

```
6800008477  4400033838  6800008477  4400033834  6800008477  4400033832  6800008477  4400033827  6800008732  4400034887
```

But as far as I undersand it should be like this to use copy_from() properly;

```
6800008477  4400033838  
6800008477  4400033834  
6800008477  4400033832  
6800008477  4400033827  
6800008732  4400034887
```

Comment: What's your question? Did you try to re-format the file accordingly and see if it works?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your comment. Secondly how can I re-format the file? My question is what is the solution for my error above? Is it about csv I mentioned or something else?

Comment: Why can't you use `COPY` instead?

Comment: It seems I will be dealing with 21 million rows.  My supervisor advised me to do like this. Maybe after I just use 'COPY' but for now I should try this

Comment: @oguzcatal You can write a simple python script that reformat it. Or use an advanced editor with macros. For example using `vim`: `vim <filename>` then press `qa2Wi<ENTER><ESC>q1000@a:wq` increase `1000` to the number of lines you need.